# Enable Macros in Outlook

Tags: outlook

I have some experience in coding VBA, some in Excel, but for years now mostly in Access.  I have never written code/macros in Outlook till yesterday.  I copied some code from this site and pasted it in a .bas file using notepad.  I then imported it into Outlook VBA successfully and gave it a test run with lots of breakpoints so I could follow it.  After a few tries I got a partial result, which was an Excel file full of email data.  I need help with the code, but today I am unable to even run it.  I get a message

> "Macros are disabled in this project etc..."

which is confusing because I was able to run this yesterday.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Macro settings in order to run Macros in Outlook.

`File-> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... -> Macro Setttings`

After that completly close Outlook (it should not even bein the tray) and start it back again. Now you should be able to run your code.

Comment: Tried that, can't.  The macro settings are grayed out and can't be changed.

Comment: @PaulH Are you in a Active Directory Domain?

Comment: Don't know what that means.  I just created a module and tried to run the code.  Yesterday it ran.  Today it won't.

Comment: @PaulH Are you in a corporate or private enviroment?

Comment: Corporate (State Gov't)

Comment: I am assuming there are some constraints from out IT contractor that I won't be able to get around, but it is odd I could run this one day and not the next.  Just tried this on another PC today and was able to run it.  Can't figure out why.

Comment: @PaulH Yeah that is why I asked